# redis how to limit the return number of KEYS command?

Tags: redis

I get values with  "KEYS p_*" command in redis.

But with "KEYS p_*" , if the redis has millions of keys,I will get too many 
values and bad performence.

So can I just get 100 values with "KEYS p_*" command?

Answer (score 69):

SCAN is recommended for production, so you can use something like:

```
SCAN 0 COUNT 100 MATCH p_*
```

and keep getting the next page 
for more details see the SCAN command: 
http://redis.io/commands/scan